# Build error: Assigning to 'id<UIPickerViewDataSource>' from incompatible type 'NSArray *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a `UIPickerView` that I am trying to set the datasource for; once the `datasource` is set, I place it into a modal popover to be displayed. Here is the code - manicuristArray is defined as `NSArray`, pvManicurist is the `UIPickerView`, all of the delegates for `UIPickerView` have been set correctly, as per samples I have found on SO):

```
    -(void) showModalManicurist:(int)tag {

    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    UIView *popoverView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 216)];
    popoverView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(300.0, 216.0);

    //  define the UIPickerView
    pvManicurist.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 216);

    //  fill the names from the d/b into manicuristArray
    PreferenceData *pv = [PreferenceData MR_findFirst];  //  (everything is in one record)
    NSLog(@"pv.aStaffPos1: %@", pv.aStaffPos1);

    if(pv)  {   //  fill the UIPickerView
        self.manicuristArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: pv.aStaffPos1, pv.aStaffPos2, pv.aStaffPos3, pv.aStaffPos4, pv.aStaffPos5,
                           pv.aStaffPos6, nil];
        NSLog(@"\nmanicuristArray.count: %d",manicuristArray.count);

        pvManicurist.dataSource = self.manicuristArray;        [pvManicurist reloadAllComponents];

     }

    //  add it to the popover
    [popoverView addSubview:pvManicurist];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView;
    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    popoverController.delegate = (id)self;
    [popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(300, 216) animated:NO];

    //  show it below the staff name textbox
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:boStaff.frame inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

The problem is I am getting this build warning:

> Build error: Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'NSArray *'

which I believe is causing the `UIPicker` view not to be put into the `UIPopover`.  I have several other popovers, all with `UIDatePickers` in them, and they work fine.  I have looked on SO and Google and found nothing that answers this particular question, which is: why is this not working? and how do I fix the build error?

**UPDATE:  here are the delegate methods for UIPickerView:**

```
//--  sets number of columns
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pvManicurist  {

    return 1; // One column
}

//--  sets count of manicuristArray
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pvManicurist numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component  {

    return manicuristArray.count;  //set number of rows
}

//--  sets the component with the values of the manicuristArray
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pvManicurist titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component  {

    return [manicuristArray objectAtIndex:row];  //set item per row
}
```

And here is the interface from the .h file:

```
@interface AppointmentsViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource  >  {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot assign an array as a data source for a data picker, because arrays do not provide the information the picker needs. In order to work correctly, the picker needs answers to at least these three questions:

- How many components a picker should have,
- How many rows each component has, and
- What data to put in each row of each component.

The data source answers the first two questions by implementing the data source protocol: you need

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
```

to return the number of components, and

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

to return the number of rows in a given component. Implement both methods in your class, and then assign

```
pvManicurist.dataSource = self;
```

Of course you need to implement methods of the delegate as well, but since you assign `popoverController.delegate = (id)self;` chances are that you have done that already.

Comment: UPDATED the question... I have added the code for the delegate method protocols... still, after making the assignment, no visible UI*PickerView, only a UIPopoverView with the red background, which I use to tell me if everything is sized correctly.

Comment: I also just noticed that the code is NOT getting to the delegate methods... why could that be?

Comment: @spokane-dude That would be tough to debug remotely. Where did you set `pvManicurist`?

Comment: Set it how?  I placed **pvManicurist.dataSource = self** in -setModalArray, replacing **pvManicurist.dataSource = self.manicuristArray;**

Comment: @spokane-dude No, I mean assigning the `pvManicurist` variable itself?

Comment: Assigning what to it?  It's the UIPickerView... I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean... I didn't build it in IB, it's all code (you can see ALL of the code above)... this is beginning to hurt my head! :D

Comment: @spokane-dude I would expect `pvManicurist = [[UIPickerView alloc] init]` or something of that nature somewhere in your code.

Comment: Awww RATS!  I didn't even think of that... I just hate it when I do something stupid like that!!  Well, at least it's showing now... but just shows question marks where the array contents should be... I'll have to experiment with that for a bit... thank you so much!  I have been working on this all day!  Arggghhhhhhh!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the assignment

```
pvManicurist.dataSource = self.manicuristArray;
```

The `dataSource` has to be an object conforming to the protocol `UIPickerViewDataSource`, i.e. an object of type `id<UIPickerViewDataSource`. Clearly `NSArray` doesn't conform to the protocol.

You need to assign a controller conforming to that protocol, not the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your receive that error message because you are trying to set an `NSArray*` as the datasource of your picker view. The datasource of your picker view should be an instance of a class that conforms to the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol.

For further information on this protocol visit [UIPickerViewDataSource Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UIPickerViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) of the iOS documentation.